IdeaVIM - issue with non-writable views
I have an issue with some non-editor views when using IdeaVIM.
If I run an application and see the log output in the Run view, then the behavior of IdeaVIM is a bit odd when I have the Run view focused. If I am in insert mode then I can't escape out of insert mode when I am browsing the log output. I need to switch to an editor view, switch out of insert mode, and then switch back to the log output so I can navigate it in Normal mode.
Another issue is when I try to view a JSON log line in IdeaVIM (Show as JSON). It seems like this view is always in Insert mode and I can't switch to Normal view to navigate this JSON file.
I think in both cases the issue is due to the views being non-writable.
Any ideas on how I can effectively use IdeaVIM in these non-editor views?
